# iOS AVAudioRecorder record without stopping background audio

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I need to allow my app to record audio without stopping background music player.

I'm using AVAudioRecorder.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

However, anytime [audioplayer record] is called, the background music will stop playing.

What can I do so that background music doesn't stop playing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MixWithOthers Category Option as well:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                       error:nil];
```